# Lazy Load no Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, lazy-loading

Não estou conseguindo fazer o Lazy Load funcionar no Spring.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura.

//Livro.Java

```java
@Entity
public class Livro {

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Campo nome é obrigatorio")
    private String nome;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyy")
    @NotNull(message = "Campo publicacao é obrigatorio")
    private Date publicacao;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String editora;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String resumo;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "livro", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<Comentario> comentarios;
```

//Comentario.Java

```java
@Entity
public class Comentario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("comentario")
    private String texto;

    private String usuario;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyy")
    private Date data;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LIVRO_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Livro livro;
```

// LivrosRepository.java

```java
package com.curso.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.curso.domain.Livro;

public interface LivrosRepository extends JpaRepository<Livro, Long> {

}
```

//ComentariosRepository.java

```java
package com.curso.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.curso.domain.Comentario;

public interface ComentariosRepository extends JpaRepository<Comentario, Long> {



}
```

// LivrosService.java

```java
@Service
public class LivrosService {

    @Autowired
    private LivrosRepository livrosRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ComentariosRepository comentariosRepository;

   // [...]

    public List<Livro> listar() {
        return livrosRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Quando faço um Request para listar os Livros, o comportamento que eu espero é que ele list todos os dados de livros, mas sem os comentários, pois estou usando a anotação `java
fetch = FetchType.LAZY` mas o comportamento que tenho é o retorno de todos os dados de Livro.

```js
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "nome": "Teste2",
        "publicacao": "01/01/2018",
        "editora": "Polenta",
        "comentarios": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "usuario": "tester",
                "data": "26/03/2019",
                "comentario": "Comentario 1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Embora você tenha declarado um `FetchType.LAZY` no seu mapeamento do JPA, o Jackson tende a obter o objeto de qualquer maneira pois este é o objetivo dele.

Não conheço sua API, mas caso você nunca queira expor os comentários, você poderia simplesmente adicionar um `@JsonIgnore` na sua lista.

Uma outra técnica também seria ter um DTO específico para seu caso para contornar esta situação.

Obs: procurei bastante aqui sobre fazer com que o Jackson entendesse este mapeamento no JPA, mas infelizmente não consegui achar nada viável. O máximo que achei foi este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989857/jackson-triggering-jpa-lazy-fetching-on-serialization) em que o autor fez de tudo para resolver o problema, mas não conseguiu.